# Matrix equations frequently in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, matrices, boldmath

I'm writing a paper. Most of the equations are of the form

`d\mathbf{F}  = (d\mathbf{X})\mathbf{AX}^T + ((d\mathbf{X})\mathbf{AX}^T)T`

Most elemets are Matrices, `A , B , C , W` but I've to use `\mathbf{A}` everytime. Is there a faster and cleaner way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define in one swoop commands `\mA`, `\mB`, and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin: % forget the auxiliary functions at the end
\cs_set_protected:Nn \__harry_define_matrix:n
 {
  \cs_new:cpn { m#1 } { \mathbf{#1} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__harry_define_matrix:n { e }
\int_step_inline:nnn { `A } { `Z }
 {
  \__harry_define_matrix:e { \char_generate:nn { #1 } { 12 } }
 }
\group_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$d\mF = (d\mX)\mA\mX^T + ((d\mX)\mA\mX^T)^T$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The “legacy” version of the code between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` is not as clean.

```
\count255=`A
\advance\count255 by -1
\loop\ifnum\count255<`Z
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \begingroup\lccode`x=\count255 \lowercase{\endgroup
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname mx\endcsname{\mathbf{x}}%
  }%
\repeat
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a new command (shortcut) which contains the tagging of `\mathbf{A}`

```
\newcommand{\mbfa}{\mathbf{A}}%
\newcommand{\mbfb}{\mathbf{B}}%
```

Then use as

```
$\mbfa \mbfb$
```

Answer (score 1):

I will adopt a macro `\mbf` where into `{}` you can write whetever letter o symbol. See this MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
$d\mbf{F}  = (d\mbf{X})\mbf{AX}^{\top} + ((d\mbf{X})\mbf{AX}^{\top})^{\top}$
\end{document}
```

[image]